# Part of project does not run on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ejb

I have a Tomcat 6 server and I'm developing a REST web service compatible with Java EE 5.

The project is developed on NetBeans 6.9.1. I deployed the project successfully, the program runs and I receive a web page in the browser. Now part of the program works. That is, I can access Java beans from the web site, I retrieve data and show it on the web page.

But I cannot access the web service. The web service is implemented using Java Enterprise Beans (EJB). Are there any libraries for EJB or REST web services missing on the server?

This is the error I see on the page:
`HTTP status 404. Description: the requested resource is not available`. What might be the problem?

This is what I get on NetBeans:

```
17-Mar-2011 18:01:14 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load java.lang.Object. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1402)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
at com.sun.faces.application.ConverterPropertyEditorFactory$DisposableClassLoader.loadClass(ConverterPropertyEditorFactory.java:447)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at java.beans.PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(PropertyEditorManager.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addPropertyEditorIfNecessary(ApplicationImpl.java:690)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:660)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:727)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:489)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:521)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1359)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
17-Mar-2011 18:01:15 com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
/WEB-INF/lib
/WEB-INF/classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the data provided one can not say whether there are libraries missing on -your- server. Only you can verify that.

From the stack trace it seems at least jersey exists somewhere (probably in the WEB-INF/lib of your .war or if the .war also runs on a full Java EE AS in Tomcat's lib directory).

Since you state that the existing code uses EJB, you should also have an EJB implementation somewhere. Tomcat does not come out of the box with EJB support, since it's only a `Servlet container`. OpenEJB would be a possible (and likely) implementation. Check that such an implementation exists somewhere.